# How to get regex for only dots?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

Here I have one image this imageName is only dots (`...............jpg`) 
I got imageName with only dots (`imageNameWithoutExtension` see cosole) if imageName has only dots, so I want only dots regex so I can compare with only dots regex with dots named imageName , How to get dots regex ?

renameFile.component.ts

```
updateFileName(){

  console.log(imageName);  // ...............jpg 
  var imageArray = imageName.split('.');
  var imageExtension = imageArray.pop();
  var imageNameWithoutExtension = imageArray.join('.');  
  console.log(imageNameWithoutExtension);  // ...............

   imageNameWithoutExtension.replace(^([,.\d]+)([,.]\d{2})$); i tried this but it gives error, how to use regex or make regex I dont know 

  'image name with only dots' // hot to get regex of only dots

  if(imageNameWithoutExtension == 'image name with only dots'){
    console.log("image name with only dots so not allowed to rename");

  }else{
    console.log("image name with not only dots so allow to rename");
  }
}
```

Comment: You want a regex for matching a string containing only dots ? Did you try something ? What was the problem ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret see my edited question i add which i tried

Comment: do you want to replace dots or just to find with dots ?

Comment: @varatharajan just find with only dots

Comment: just try this `str = "...............jpg"
console.log(str.match(/^[\.]+[a-zA-Z]{3}$/))` I am assuming jpg can be JPG too.

Comment: @varatharajan I removed jpg(extension already using pop and split) and i doing as per ur suggestion but I got null in console    console.log(imageNameWithoutExtension.match(/^[\.]+[a-zA-Z]{3}$/));

Comment: do you want to keep your image name as dots only.

Comment: yes I want to check In if condition if I got imageName with dots or not ?

Comment: @varatharajan I have imageName .......................jpg now i remove extension using split and pop now i have imageName like this ....................... so I want only dots regex so I can compare if(imageName == 'dots regex'){ console.log("imagename is only with dots")}

Comment: @DenysSéguret I have imageName .......................jpg now i remove extension using split and pop now i have imageName like this ....................... so I want only dots regex so I can compare if(imageName == 'dots regex'){ console.log("imagename is only with dots")}

Comment: I don't know answer in regex, but by this solution you can achieve the same thing : let str = ".............";
if(str.split(".").join("")  == ""){
  console.log("name has only dots");
}

Comment: @DDD I posted an answer. check and let me know.

Comment: @DDD Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
imageName.match(/^[\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}$/)
```

if your file may not have extension then

```
imageName.match(/^[\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}$/)
```

Comment: I tried this  console.log(imageNameWithoutExtension.match(/^[\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}$/)); but in console I got null, I already remove image extension

Comment: because this extension based. does your file has extension?

Comment: I want to check in if condition If I got imageName with only dots or not ? see my question

Comment: your question is not clear, but I edited my answer. iI believe that it will work

Comment: I have imageName .......................jpg now i remove extension using split and pop now i have imageName like this ....................... so I want only dots regex so I can compare if(imageName == 'dots regex'){ console.log("imagename is only with dots")}

Comment: @DDD from your previous reply, it clearly shows you have a imageName has only dots (.....................) then this `/^[\.]+$/` is enough to check. if you use above accepted answer in that condition it will not only allow dots. it will allow dots, alphanumeric characters too.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you wants,

```js
var updateFileName = function () {
    var imageName = "...............jpg"
    console.log(imageName);  // ...............jpg 
    var imageArray = imageName.split('.');
    var imageExtension = imageArray.pop();
    var imageNameWithoutExtension = imageArray.join('.');
    console.log(imageNameWithoutExtension);  // ...............
    var flag = false
    if (imageNameWithoutExtension.match(/^[\.]+$/)) {
        flag = true
    }
    if (flag) {
        console.log("image name with only dots so not allowed to rename");

    } else {
        console.log("image name with not only dots so allow to rename");
    }
}
updateFileName()
```

Comment: @DDD inside if condition you want to check whether  imageNameWithoutExtension  has only dots or not. Am I right ?